# Kurento media server in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, webrtc, kurento

I am following the **Kurento** documentation to set up a **Kurento Media Server 6.0** (KMS) in a **Ubuntu 14.04 AWS instance** and I am not able to make the Hello World tutorial work.

I edited the WebRtcEndpoint.conf.ini file to use Public Free STUN/TURN servers:

```
stunServerAddress=74.125.142.127
stunServerPort=19302
```

For the TURN I use a free one available here http://numb.viagenie.ca/.

I used [this](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) tool to check the status of those servers and they seem to be working.(srflx for the STUN and relay for the TURN)

Then, I do

> service kurento-media-server-6.0 start

**KMS seems to work**. In the Logs I see:

> `KurentoMediaServer main.cpp main() Mediaserver started`

I follow the steps for running one of the github kurento tutorial codes:

```
git clone https://github.com/Kurento/kurento-tutorial-js.git

cd kurento-tutorial-js/kurento-hello-world 

bower install 

http-server -p 8443 -S -C keys/server.crt -K keys/server.key
```

And, although I am able to see the web page and see my local media streaming when I start, I am not able to see anything in the remote. I am stuck on trying to make the KMS to transmit the streaming. Also, I noticed that in the KMS logs it says "Secure websocket server not enabled", I am not sure if this is relevant...

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

**Solved:**

Thanks to igracia I went to [here](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html#configure-kurento-media-server-to-use-secure-websocket-wss). Then after configuring Kurento to use wss I still wasn't able to make the tutorial work. I needed to do one last thing. Accessing KMS, by default at the port *8433*, not 8443, and accepting the certificate. Then I went to my web client at the port *8443* and everything worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your browser console, you'll see a mixed content error indicating that you are trying to connect to a non-secure url from a secure origin. You need to configure KMS to expose a WSS port, so that your web client connects directly to that. Follow [this](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mastering/securing-kurento-applications.html#configure-javascript-applications-to-use-https) guide about how to secure JavaScript applications, and configuring your KMS to expose that secure WS connection.